# approximation of the hypoexponential distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, approximation

I'm trying to find a closed form for the hypoexponential distribution (the sum of exponentially distributed RVs with different rates).
Does anybody have an idea about an approximation for this distribution? mainly if I can get rid of the product term in the expression, even by approximation.

The formula is as follows:

$f_x(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} (\prod\limits_{j\neq i}\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_j-\lambda_i}) \lambda_i exp(-\lambda_i x)$

Comment: If $k$ is large and the $\lambda_i$ are not too different, you can use the Central Limit Theorem to approximate this by a normal distribution.

Comment: More specifically, see [Lindeberg's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition).  This is of course assuming the RV's are independent, which you forgot to state.

Comment: Thank you, @Robert, for the suggestion. However, in my case, the rates ($\lambda$) are very large with a very high difference between them.

Comment: If the $\lambda_i$ are very different, then in some intervals you may say that some of the $\exp(-\lambda_i x)$ (with $\lambda_i x >>1$) are very close to $0$ while others with $\lambda_i x << 1$ are very close to $1$.  To say more would require more details about the $\lambda_i$.

Comment: The thing is that the rates are random with some distribution. According to simulation, the pdf looks something like a log-normal distribution or a Generalized Extreme Value distribution, where the range is very small (0 to 10^-8).